# find basis for $W=\{ p(t) \in p_2 (\mathbb{R}):p'(1)=p(2) \}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W=\{ p(t)\in P_2 (\mathbb{R} : p'(1)=p(2)) \}$

***I am unsure about (ii)***

i) Determine wheter W is a vector subspaces of $P_2(R)$

ii) If it is, then find a basis for W

---

**Thm** W is a vector space

existence of zero  $0 \in W$

closed scalar mult $ax\in W$ when $x\in W,a\in F$

closed add. $x+y\in W$

---

*Here is what I have*

**part (i)**

**Existence of Zero**
**$0\in W$**  since
   $$\begin{aligned}
(0)'&=0(2)
\\0&=0    
 \end{aligned}$$
(badly worded but whatever)

**Closed under scalar addition**

Suppose $p(t) \in W$ so $p'(1)=p(2).$ Is $a*p(t)\in W$ so $ap'(1)=ap(2)$ and it is the case that $ap(t)\in W$

**Closed under vector addition** Also assume $g(t) \in W$ so $g'(1)=g(2)$ now is $p(t)+g(t)\in W$ ?

Well $$ p'(1) +g'(1)=p(1)+g(1) $$
So it is the case that $p(t)+g(t) \in W$

Since W is closed under addition, scalar mult and also zero exist in W then W is a vector subspace of $P_2 (\mathbb{R})$

Let $P(t)=a+bx+cx^2,p'(t)=b+c2x$
$$\begin{aligned} 
p'(1)&=p(2)
\\b+2x&=a+2b+4c
\\0&=a+b+2c
\end{aligned} $$ 
Deadend Road

$p(t)=(ax+b) $, $p'(t)=a$
$$ \begin{aligned}
p'(a)&=p(2)
\\ a    &=2a+b
\\ -a &=b
\end{aligned}$$
 So, ax-a=a(x-1), our first element of basis is $x-1$

another, Let $p(t)=ax^2+b, p'(t)=2ax+0$

$$\begin{aligned} z'(1)&=z(2) 
                 \\2a&=4a+b
                 \\-2a&=b\end{aligned} $$
 So $ax^2-2a=a(x^2-2)$ and we have so far that our basis is $\{ x^2-2,x-1\}$

Not sure there is another element in our basis. What I would do is find another one then rref by hand   to see if the 3 are linearly independent. This was a test question ( costed me  close to a letter grade) and that way  eats to much time. Not to sure how to find the dimension of $W$ since the transformation is not explicit. What is the most efficient way to find the basis that is what my question boils down to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you wrote "Deadend road" you already have it all, but the rest of your work *is alright*!

Observe that you showed a polynomial $\;a+bx+cx^2\in P_2(\Bbb R)\;$ is in $\;W\iff a+b+2c=0\;$ , and this last is a plane in 3-dimensional space, so $\;\dim W=2\;$ and since you already got two linearly independent vectors in $\;W\;$ you're done.